# .vimrc: E474: Invalid argument: bs=4

Tags: vim

In my .vimrc, I changed `set bs=2` to `set bs=4`.

Now I get this error:

```
E474: Invalid argument: bs=4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get that error because `4` is not a valid value for `backspace`. The possible values are `indent`, `eol`, `start`, nothing, `0`, `1`, and `2`. `0` is a shortcut for nothing, which means to use Vi compatible backspacing. `1` is a shortcut for `indent,eol`. `2` is a shortcut for `indent,eol,start`.

For an explanation of what each value does, check out [:help backspace](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27backspace%27).

Answer (score 1):

`4` is not a valid value for the `backspace` option. Do you confuse it with another option like `tabstop`?

Don't use short names in your `~/.vimrc`: you get no benefit and only drawbacks.

Use Vim's awesome documentation instead of your web browser: `:help 'bs`.

Comment: I had totally confused it with the number of spaces. Added this option years ago.

Comment: And +1 to the documentation. Didn't know it was so awesome!